# How to treat a question which was partly answered, but not completely?

Tags: discussion

I have a dilemma: I asked a question which got two replies. The first reply giving very good hints to solve the issue, the second (maybe more of a comment) extends the first answer and improves it. Neither of the two answers were 100% solving my problem, but by deriving from the work of those authors, I was able to get a working solution. How should I give credits now?

**Variant 1**

- Add correct solution to my own question
- Accept first post (which did give the main hints)
- Upvote extending post

I think this to be the correct solution, but I have some concerns in posting a reply in my own question. Is this accepted usage of SO?

**Variant 2**

- Add correct solution as answer and accept own answer
- Upvote the 2 precedent posters to give credit for the correct hints.

This would probably be the correct treatment in terms of Q&A on SO, but I do not want to rob the merited reputation of any of the original repliers.

Since this propably won't ever be a very famous question, I feel especially responsible to do it right since not very much reputation will be gained aside the points I credit.

Maybe there is a better solution? Which one would you go for?

Comment: It's accepted to answer your own question, you'll even earn a badge for that. But do that as long as you feel that you added something new to the already existing posts that's not straightforward to conclude.

Comment: @MarounMaroun It's not really anything additional, it's just combining the two answers.

Comment: Ive seen many cases where the OP was edited, or even some with a self-answer, and ive always appreciated that in those cases they gave credit to original answer but also elaborated on the extra steps or just explained in more detail how they used that to achieve the result. That almost always gets an upvote from me, as well as the referanced answer (if i think it complete enough to warrant it). There are ALSO cases OP can leave out details and be unintentionally vague on context - so in some cases its simply that the answerer couldnt have known - so i sometimes check OP edits

Comment: @DanielB I agree - I think I'm going to do it exactly that way and add the exact solution to the OP giving credit by accepting the answer of the first guy. Would my own change have been much larger than just a one liner I'd propably have posted it as answer.

Comment: @Marwie - you prob already know, but i found nested <br/> tags in the post great way to seperate - a bit of whitespace between text bodies in the edited OP is prob all you need, so long as you put a note near the top that you adapted [name]'s answer below

Comment: @DanielBrose just did that - I actually didn't know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that situation it seems both answers were helpful to you and led to your solution, so you may want to upvote both of them from the start.

I don't think adding your own answer which is essentially a combination of the two is going to be that beneficial unless you also include a full working demo of the entire situation. If a full demo was included then that seems like it would contain enough new information to at least be a relevant answer as opposed to just a summary of what was already present. Then you could accept that one. I don't think that this is very ideal though.

What is probably best would be to leave a comment on the post which contributed most towards your solution indicating how that progress was gained and possibly accept that answer. In this scenario you should probably not edit the original question you posed. It is also an option to simply not accept either answer as neither one was a full solution, but it would be best for future users if one of them was marked as a signpost to indicate "this answer helped me solve my problem".

So for this exact scenario ([Howto fix Backgroundcolor bleeding in bordered ToolStripStatusLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655565/howto-fix-backgroundcolor-bleeding-in-bordered-toolstripstatuslabel) I believe) I would go with accepting the first post which helped you the most, upvoting both, leaving a comment on the accepted post indicating which avenue or aspect led to your final solution, and moving on.